# How do I create subtasks in Celery

Tags: python, celery, celerybeat

I am trying to loop through many `buildings` in my db. In each building I generate a bill for each `apt` in that `building`. This all happens on a scheduled task in `Celery` on the 25th of each month.  The bill is sent out for the next month. I know I can use `chords` and `groups` and other subtasks I am just confused as to how to organize it into one giant working mechanism.  This is what I tried so far (which does not work). I am testing using `crontab` and a current time just so I can see it run. In production I'll set that date to the 25th of each month.

**config.py**:

```
CELERY_TIMEZONE = 'America/New_York'
CELERYBEAT_SCHEDULE = {
    "billing-schedule": {
        "task": "tasks.bill_all_buildings",
        "schedule": crontab(hour=8,minute=41)
    },
}
```

**tasks.py**:

```
@celery.task()
def bill_all_buildings():
    for building in Building.query.all():
        if building.billing_on:
            print 'billing %s' % building.name
            bill_apts_in_building.delay(building)

@celery.task()
def bill_apts_in_building(building):
    for apt in building.apts:
        print 'billing apt %s' % apt.last_name
        create_apt_bill.delay(apt)

@celery.task()
def create_apt_bill(apt):
    money_helpers.bill_next_month(apt)
```

In the what happens is that `bill_all_buildings` gets run and then it says:

```
[2014-01-31 07:28:00,036: DEBUG/MainProcess] Task accepted: tasks.bill_apts_in_building[da7b46f2-e559-4947-9442-bd31329d8d0d] pid:9156
```

Then nothing happens.

Comment: The code looks fine to me. Are you sure that the buildings loop is actually getting executed? Does the print statement in `bill_all_buildings` outputs anything ?

Comment: @SunnyNanda Yes it does output the building name for the first building. It does not output anything after it says task accepted

Comment: None of these functions return anything, does the `celery.task()` decorator make the functions return something implicitly?

Comment: Dumb question: does the building have any apts? Did you set a print before the loop on the second task?

Comment: @Germano You are right for some reason my query to the db is returning an empty list: `[]`. It does not make sense because I can query the db  any other time in the app and it works fine. For some reason in this context it does not work right.